# Are dicts always the most efficient way to store hashes in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, hashmap

In many languages there are numerous different implementations of the hash map/associative array, each suited to different tasks. In Python as far as I know there's just dict.

So I guess what I'm wondering is, are there any applications for which a customized data structure makes sense? Or will it always be slower than using one of Python's built in data structures?

Comment: Have a look at dictobject.c - it's marvelous how much thought, math, and benchmarking went into it. Also consider that you'll start out with a constant slow down of at least 10x, possible up to 100x, if you implement it in Python.

Comment: You may want to watch this [PyCon video](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147) regarding the mighty dict

Comment: "In many languages there are numerous different implementations of the hash map/associative array, each suited to different tasks." I must be tired, but could you provide some example of those "different implementations" available in some mainstream script language?

Comment: Not necessarily *scripting* languages, but just off the top of my head Java has many implementations of the Map data structure http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html which is similar to python's dict.

Comment: @JordanReiter Note that this interface is implemented by some classes which aren't stand-alone implementations at all, but just specialized subclasses of/wrappers around `HashTable` (which one can and does create in Python too): Attributes, AuthProvider, PrinterStateReasons, Properties, Provider, RenderingHints, SimpleBindings, TabularDataSupport, UIDefaults. Other implementations have an equivalent in Python: `WeakHashMap` is `weakred.WeakKeyDictionary` and `LinkedHashMap` is `collections.OrderedDict`. There still are a few truly different implementations, and Scala have more examples.

Comment: @JordanReiter In addition, two of those implementations aren't a hash tables but binary search trees, which entails a much more general interface (SortedMap). Including those is arguable (though not completely wrong) - it *is* a different thing, but the use cases where it can't be replaced by hash tables are rare and narrow, and Python doesn't have binary search trees at all (in the standard library).

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be in comment, but far too long so...

Python dictionary are implemented as as [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Hash tables are good to retrieve items *on average* ( O(1) ). If they are generally good, their performances decrease when there are a lot of *collisions*. A collision is when the computed hash for two different keys is the same. So at worst, that is if all the keys have the same hash, their complexity for the search operation is in O(n) -- that is the equivalent of a linear search.

But [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) could be implemented by using several other data structures. Notably [binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (not that good: O(log n) on average, O(n) at worst) or [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) (better: O(log n) on average *and* at worst). AFAIK the standard Python library does not provide any of those. By *googling* a little, it seems to have various implementation hanging around.

That leads to the core of your question: "are there any applications for which a customized data structure makes sense? Or will it always be slower than using one of Python's built in data structures?". As of myself, I think any pure-Python implementation of any of these data structures will probably be slowly that native Python dictionary. If you have very special needs, you might consider implementing those at C-level. But if you have such constraints, maybe Python wasn't the best choice at first.